# media9 doesn't give correct output

Tags: beamer, xetex, media9, output

usually I can fix all problems myself concerning...like...everything, but this really is a hard one, so... sry to bother you.

**Problem:**

Creating a beamer presentation (with university corp. design) that includes a mp4 file. I'm working on 3 different windows7-64bit machines with Miktex 2.9 installed (some 64bit, some 32bit). In order to include the clip, the media9 package is employed.

Now the funny thing: It works on my home system without any problems, but on my laptop as well as on my office PC I get the warning

> **WARNING** Could not find any valid object

and the video is included but distorted and you can still see the "play" dummy in the background
--> see picture

No usable results from google. Log file tells some errors like

> Missing character: There is no XXX in font nullfont!

where XXX is a single line a character from

> (0,0)circle(0,4);bpbp

I think the problem is there somewhere.

I already tried:

- minimal example using default beamer class
- re-installing Miktex in 32/64 bit
- switching to  pdflatex
- updating Miktex repos and files

No notable changes.

Any ideas? :)

[image: pic]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Please state the versions of media9 and Acrobat being used. Also what is the flash SWF player that you are using?

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment but, don't have enough reputation (yet). 
I've met this problem and could solve it upgrading Miktex2.9 from http://miktex.org/download, but only get to work in Windosws 7 (64bit) with Miktex2.9 also 64 bit version. 
Office machine is Windows 7 32 bit, and updating Miktex doesn't solve the problem.

This is an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\includemedia[addresource=random.mp4,activate=pageopen,flashvars=          {source=random.mp4}]{\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]
{esquema1}}{VPlayer.swf}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Works on Win7-64bit and  Miktex2.9 64bit (v.2.9.5105) and it doesn't work in Win7-32bit with Miktex2.9 32bit (v.2.9.5105)